# JS Permission denied when trying to reload parent for https pages

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reload the parent page from the child window and I used
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href.

This worked when both pages were on http, but since they were moved on https, I get Permission denied for property href.
Do you have any idea how could I refresh the parent?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to do so in HTTPS mode as it has more restriction due to its security. You might be able to call a function tho, so that the opener offer a function that when called refresh its location. I suspect the problem is that https windows refuse to allow others to change their location.

Comment: an which is that function that I can call to refresh the parent?

Answer (score 0):

http and https are considered separate domains since the protocols are different. You can not access them because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: So there is no way that I can refresh the parent?